# " keyword not supported 'file access retry timeout' " when creating a new SQL server compact database?

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I am receiving the following error when I try to create a new SQL Server Compact Database using the Server Explorer. "Keyword not Supported 'file access retry timeout'.
I am following the instructions from the following page keyword not supported http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983322.aspx
The error occurs during step number 6.
In the textbox where it says "Enter the new SQL Server Compact Database FileName "; No matter what file name I enter and what path I provide, I get that error.
for example. D:\MySQLDB
The error comes.

Why is this happening and what should I do to fix this ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install SQL Server Compact 4 SP1, as the mentioned keyword was introduced with this Service Pack

Comment: This fixed for me.